# Counting Iterations in recursion

Tags: python, function, recursion, iteration

I'm trying to keep track of iterations through this recursion, but 'iter' always returns 1.

```
def compute_root(poly, x_0, epsilon): ##Using Newton's method
    iter = 0
    try:
        if abs(evalpoly(poly,x_0)) < epsilon:
            return '%s is the root. Took %s iterations.'%(x_0,iter)
        else:
            iter += 1
            x_1 = x_0 - (evalpoly(poly,x_0)/evalderiv(poly,x_0))
            return compute_root(poly, x_1, epsilon)

    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print 'No root.'
```

I'm thinking it's because I have to actually return iter += 1 but I'm not sure. . . Sorry if this is an elementary question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass iter to the function you are recursively calling:

```
def compute_root(poly, x_0, epsilon, iter=None): ##Using Newton's method
    if iter is None:
        iter = 0
    try:
        if abs(evalpoly(poly,x_0)) < epsilon:
            return '%s is the root. Took %s iterations.'%(x_0,iter)
        else:
            iter += 1
            x_1 = x_0 - (evalpoly(poly,x_0)/evalderiv(poly,x_0))
            return compute_root(poly, x_1, epsilon, iter=iter)

    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print 'No root.'
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense :)

Comment: When learning recursion, something like this can be very helpful: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit Give it a shot and it will help you visualize the stack frames

Comment: You are welcome. I think it's a nice tool and good for visualizing things like recursion.

Answer (score 2):

The first line in the function will reset iter to 0 on every recursive call.

You can use a variable outside of the function to track this or pass the running total as an argument.